# How to insert string in multiple continuous pattern in windows c#

Tags: c#, regex, windows

I want to insert string between symbol but the symbol is continuous. Like 'xx;;string;;;string;;string;;;;'

I can use `Regex r = new Regex(@";;", RegexOptions.Singleline);text = r.Replace(text, ";na;");`, but the output will be `xx;na;string;na;;string;na;string;na;;na;`

What I want is `xx;na;string;na;na;string;na;string;na;na;na;`
I want all empty space between ";;" to have na in it.

Is there any C# function can achieve this?

Comment: This `.Replace(";;", ";na;")` does not yield the expected result.

Comment: Run your regex twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `;(?=;)` regex with a lookahead to match `;` followed with another `;` without consuming the second `;`:

```
var str = "xx;;string;;;string;;string;;;;";
var res = Regex.Replace(str, ";(?=;)", ";na");
Console.WriteLine(res); // => xx;na;string;na;na;string;na;string;na;na;na;
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/vQwvx8) and the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3b%28%3f%3d%3b%29&i=xx%3b%3bstring%3b%3b%3bstring%3b%3bstring%3b%3b%3b%3b&r=%3bna).

The `(?=;)` is a [*positive lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that only checks if there is a `;` immediately to the left of the current location, but does not add it to the match value (so it is not removed) and does not move the regex index (so that same `;` can be matched again during the next iteration).

Comment: appreciate the answer